# Taskbar icon not showing for winforms

Tags: .net, winforms

I am just doing some testing with building a winforms application that is to be called from a class library  from VBA. I started a vb.net winforms project in VS2013, created a test form then changed the application type from a windows forms application to a class library.

I referenced the dll in the VBA editor and called the form using.

```
Public viewer testPDF.Form1

Sub viewer()
    set viewer = new testPDF.Form1
    viewer.show
End Sub
```

This works however I am unable to get a icon for the form in the taskbar. I have checked the form properties and both ShowInTaskBar = true and FormBorderStyle = Sizable. Alt-tab shows the form properly as well and the default icon shows correctly in the window header.

I have looked through other similar questions on stackoverflow, some of which suggest that re-setting the form properties in the shown event solves the issue. I have tested this:

```
Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.Sizable
    Me.ShowInTaskbar = True
    Me.BringToFront()
End Sub
```

However it still does not solve the issue.

Can anyone offer any advice on where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Run your app on another machine.  If you now do see the appropriate icon then you want to google "reset shell icon cache".

Comment: Thanks for that Hans. All works fine on a separate test machine so I will look into resetting the shell icon cache.